# How to order an array in managed C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

Here is my array :

```
cli::array<String^>^ ar = gcnew cli::array<String^>{ "3", "1", "4", "5", "2" };
```

How can i **Order By Descending** this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) by passing a comparison function.

```
using namespace System;

int Compare(String^ a, String^ b)
{
    return String::Compare(a, b, StringComparison::OrdinalIgnoreCase) * -1;
}

auto ar = gcnew cli::array<String^>{ "3", "1", "4", "5", "2" };
Array::Sort(ar, gcnew Comparison<String^>(Compare));
```

Alternately, you can sort with an ascending order and [reverse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx) the array.

```
Array::Sort(ar, StringComparer::OrdinalIgnoreCase);
Array::Reverse(ar);
```